# IBM Worklight JSONStore changePassword API

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

The changePassword API of JSONStore works on the complete store or on a single collection ?
And after changing the password, do we need to close and re-initialise the collection/store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Each collection can have its own password, as such you can change the password per-collection.
2. It is not required to re-initialize the collection, but it does have to be initialized.